# how to communicate with uci protocol using matlab

Tags: matlab, chess

I'm looking for a method to communicate with a chess engine with uci protocol using matlab.
The chess engine is rybka and its an exe file. When I run the rybka.exe, I can communicate via dos command prompt but I want do that via matlab.
I think I have to use streampipe and stdin and stdout but I don't know how use it.

I found this code in Python and it works fine but I'm looking for a matlab version:

```
import subprocess, time

engine = subprocess.Popen(
    'a.exe',
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)

def put(command):
    print('\nyou:\n\t'+command)
    engine.stdin.write(command+'\n')

def get():
    # using the 'isready' command (engine has to answer 'readyok')
    # to indicate current last line of stdout
    engine.stdin.write('isready\n')
    print('\nengine:')
    while True:
        text = engine.stdout.readline().strip()
        if text == 'readyok':
            break
        if text !='':
            print('\t'+text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a case of using the exe file and capturing the output you can use the `system` command to capture the output.  For example I can run the system's `dir` command in the following way:

```
>> [~, output] = system('dir')

output =

ant      ant.cmd  antRun.bat  antenv.cmd           envset.cmd  runant.pl
ant.bat  antRun   antRun.pl   complete-ant-cmd.pl  lcp.bat     runant.py
```

Documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

See also: [Running C program's executable from Matlab and getting the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734478/running-c-programs-executable-from-matlab-and-getting-the-output)