# Running C program's executable from Matlab and getting the output

Tags: matlab

I compiled a C program in Visual Studio Express 2010.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");

}
```

This produces a file "hello.exe" on my C drive. In Matlab, I use this command,

```
! hello
```

And it prints "Hello World" to my Matlab console.

What is the name of the `!` Matlab command? I have been trying to find documentation for it but is having difficulty because I don't know what keywords to Google for. Thanks!

**Additional Info**

I will be running a fairly complicated C program that outputs a plain text file. Then using Matlab to read the text file, put the data into matrices/arrays and manipulate these in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this?

http://www.mathworks.se/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/system.html

I think it's what you're looking for =)

**Edit:**

Also, if you type:

```
help !
```

You will get the name (amongst other stuff):

```
punct - Invoke operating system command - !
```

Comment: Great answer.  Just to be clear though, that documentation page is for running the `system` command from mupad.  The page for the MATLAB documentation is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

Comment: Thanks @Huguenot for the input. Though the page you linked does not explain "!".

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up point.  If you are spending a lot of time writing C utility functions that you would like to use in MATLAB, you should consider turning them into MEX functions.  A MEX function is a MATLAB function that uses C/C++/Fortran code in the background, allowing you to save the output of those external functions directly into your MATLAB workspace.

For more information, you can read through this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/create-mex-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the [dos](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dos.html) command.  It'll let you capture the output of other executables.

Comment: I just need the C code to read a text file and output another text file that will be read by Matlab.