# UCI Communication Protocol with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, protocols, chess

I've recently created a chess engine on MATLAB and have been trying to interface it with XBoard/WinBoard. I can't find any good source on how to do this with MATLAB, this includes how to make my engine (an .m file) into an .exe file, as well as including the actual UCI communication protocols in it.

Any help or insight on the topic would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460383/how-to-communicate-with-uci-protocol-using-matlab) and [this MATLAB Central submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25775-chess-with-greedy-edi) for UCI communication from MATLAB.

Regarding creation of a standalone .exe, you will need to use the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) or [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/):

- MATLAB Compiler.  Can generate executables with using **any** functions.  Requires the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) libraries at runtime.
- MATLAB Coder.  Can generate C++ code (and executables) with a **subset** of MATLAB's functions.  Does **not require** the MCR at runtime.